# How To MOUNT A LUKS Encrypted Linux Filesystem Unlocked Partition VIA USB on another LINUX OS to retrieve files

Tags: mount, partition, usb, luks

Ive been at this all day. I've scoured the web and this board and have tried many solutions to this issue but nothing has seemed to work. Someone on here asked a similar question and the solution did not help.

I feel I'm close but don't know how to follow through. Pulled my NVME drive and hooked it via USB to my Linux Mint machine. I can see the drive and I can unlock the drive with my passphrase but I can't mount it. Shouldn't it mount when I unlock it?

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to get this to mount?

Do I have to decrypt the main LVM2 Physical Volume (LVM2 001) first? or just focus on the LUKS partition?

below is some of info and line commands Ive tried. Thank you all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                            
├─sda1      ext4         a7987e8b-cdc7-43b8-9d3f-0fe58103bd71    160.7M    70% /boot
├─sda2                                                                         
└─sda5      crypto       44697cdf-8332-4595-870d-21296693002e                  
  └─sda5_crypt
            LVM2_m       QXqf19-8D7z-W9pC-QkI2-t8Hc-CCek-XuH9TU                
    ├─mint--vg-root
    │       ext4         bb06e16e-d776-4282-88d2-c91120979c02      1.6T     4% /run/times
    └─mint--vg-swap_1
            swap         25824eea-25c6-453a-8d21-704fd2a4be90                  [SWAP]
sdd                                                                            
├─sdd1      vfat         DCEE-4749                                             
├─sdd2      ext4         71f85328-bae1-4179-9a6a-8cf6661730e7    342.2M    44% /media/t/7
└─sdd3      crypto       2e3b8613-e988-4aff-a4ba-0915ce305bb4                  
  └─crypted_sdd3
            LVM2_m       1UwgAt-xngX-SlvP-bl8w-0rRu-pLGt-XcBHYN
```

```
$ sudo lvs
  LV     VG      Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   mint-vg -wi-------  <1.82t                                                    
  root   mint-vg -wi-ao----  <1.82t                                                    
  swap_1 mint-vg -wi------- 976.00m                                                    
  swap_1 mint-vg -wi-ao---- 976.00m
```

```
$ sudo vgs
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  mint-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- <1.82t    0 
  mint-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- <1.82t    0
```

I've tried to mount sdd3 many times and no luck

```
$ mount /dev/sdd3
mount: /dev/sdd3: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/recoverytarget /mnt/recoverytarget
mount: /mnt/recoverytarget: special device /dev/mapper/recoverytarget does not exist.
```

```
$ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdd3 luksrecoverytarget --type luks

Enter passphrase for /dev/sdd3: 
Device luksrecoverytarget already exists.
```

```
$ sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdd3
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sdd3 crypto       2e3b8613-e988-4aff-a4ba-0915ce305bb4                  
└─crypted_sdd3
     LVM2_m       1UwgAt-xngX-SlvP-bl8w-0rRu-pLGt-XcBHYN
```

```
$ sudo /dev/mapper/crypted_sdd3 /mnt/2e3b8613-e988-4aff-a4ba-0915ce305bb4 ext4 defaults 0 0
sudo: /dev/mapper/crypted_sdd3: command not found
```

```
$ sudo mount -av
/                        : ignored
/boot                    : already mounted
none                     : ignored
```

```
$ sudo blkid | grep crypto
/dev/sda5: UUID="44697cdf-8332-4595-870d-21296693002e" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="5f1dfb0d-05"
/dev/sdc3: UUID="2e3b8613-e988-4aff-a4ba-0915ce305bb4" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="0be31b07-df9d-43c6-a0d4-ef4e8be65bd0"
```

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc3/ crypthome
Device /dev/sdc3/ doesn't exist or access denied.
```

```
$ sudo vgchange -an --select vg_uuid=f0u7eE-zgoH-mDLS-x7Rs-3RGe-uoob-OFcht2 Volume group "mint-vg" successfully changed 0 logical volume(s) in volume group "mint-vg" now active
```

```
$ sudo vgexport --select vg_uuid=f0u7eE-zgoH-mDLS-x7Rs-3RGe-uoob-OFcht2 Volume group "mint-vg" successfully exported
```

```
$ sudo pvscan
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/luksrecoverytarget at 0 length 512.
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/luksrecoverytarget at 0 length 4096.
  PV /dev/mapper/luks-2e3b8613-e988-4aff-a4ba-0915ce305bb4    is in exported VG mint-vg [<1.82 TiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt                                  VG mint-vg         lvm2 [<1.82 TiB / 0    free]
  Total: 2 [<3.64 TiB] / in use: 2 [<3.64 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

```
$ sudo vgimport --select vg_uuid=f0u7eE-zgoH-mDLS-x7Rs-3RGe-uoob-OFcht2
  Volume group "mint-vg" successfully imported
```

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/--select vg_uuid=f0u7eE-zgoH-mDLS-x7Rs-3RGe-uoob-OFcht2/users
```

```
$ sudo mount /dev/--select vg_uuid=f0u7eE-zgoH-mDLS-x7Rs-3RGe-uoob-OFcht2/users
mount: /home/t/vg_uuid=f0u7eE-zgoH-mDLS-x7Rs-3RGe-uoob-OFcht2/users: special device /dev/--select does not exist.
```

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/luks-2e3b8613-e988-4aff-a4ba-0915ce305bb4 /mnt/recoverytarget
mount: /mnt/recoverytarget: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/recoverytarget
mount: /mnt/recoverytarget: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.
```

```
$ sudo vgimport --select vg_uuid=f0u7eE-zgoH-mDLS-x7Rs-3RGe-uoob-OFcht2 /dev/sdb3
  Volume group "sdb3" not found
  Cannot process volume group sdb3
```

Comment: I've only skim read this but it looks like you are using LVM. It looks like your encrypted partition is an encrypted PV. You might need to [import the volume group](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recipemovevgtonewsys.html)

Comment: That is correct. Is that normal for it to be a physical volume? I will take a look at importing the volume group import to get it mounted. Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming that physical volume is normal for Linux mint, because I chose full drive encryption. It is exactly the same as the Linux mint computer I am trying to decrypt and mount the drive from my other computer on.

Comment: If my main system and my other system that I have plugged in via USB-C both have the same mint-vg volume group name then I would use the volume group UUID correct? How would one pick the right one? I suppose I could run vgdisplay with the drive unplugged, but what command could I use if I didn't want to unplug? I think I was using the UUID instead of VG UUID?

Comment: I imported the volume group but now I am having trouble making the directory and mounting the directory. Do I use mint-vg instead of the volume UUID? How will it know to mount the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a filesystem on top of LVM on top of LUKS partition.

The system can automatically hot-plug the disk, read the partition table and auto-detect the partition table, but because the next layer is LUKS, the automatic processing will stop there.

You'll need to proceed through the remaining layers in order.

First, `sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdd3 luksrecoverytarget  --type luks` will unlock the LUKS layer and present it in unencrypted form as `/dev/mapper/luksrecoverytarget`.

But in your case, it's not a straight filesystem, but a LVM physical volume. Before the filesystem can be accessed, the LVM volume group needs to be activated first.

Depending on the udev rules of your distribution, the system may or may not auto-detect the LVM volume group on creation of `/dev/mapper/luksrecoverytarget`. To be sure, you can run `sudo vgscan` after unlocking the LUKS layer: this way, you will also see an error message if all the parts of the volume group are not accessible (e.g. if the volume group has been extended to another disk in its original location). After that, the normal procedure would be to run `sudo vgchange -ay` to explicitly attempt to activate any detected LVM volume groups.

But you seem to have the additional complication of a volume group naming conflict: if the name of the volume group matches the name of an already existing VG, you'll need to change the name of the VG before you can activate it.

To deconflict the VG on the transferred disk, you'll need to identify the VG to rename by its LVM VG UUID. You'll need a command like this:

```
sudo vgrename f0u7eE-zgoH-mDLS-x7Rs-3RGe-uoob-OFcht2 recoverymint-vg
```

After that, you should be able to activate the VG with

```
sudo vgchange -ay recoverymint-vg
```

Since a LVM volume group may contain more than one filesystem (even if it's just one LVM physical volume), the typical auto-mount systems may consider it too complex for auto-mounting. So the next step would be to run e.g. `sudo lvs` to verify the name(s) of the LVM logical volume(s) contained within the volume group, and then mount it.

---

In Linux LVM2 (= the current, non-ancient version), the `vgexport`/`vgimport` commands are only really needed when you are making a planned move of LVM disks containing a VG that is known or suspected to cause a conflict on the destination system.

Essentially running `vgexport` on the source system before the disk(s) are moved will tell the destination system "I'm pretty sure you don't want me; find the other one with the same name". This enables the destination system to boot successfully even in the presence of a VG name conflict.

If you add the disks to the destination system by hot-plugging, LVM is smart enough to prefer an already activated VG over a suddenly appearing potential usurper that just happens to have the same name, but a different VG UUID.

Even a cloned VG with the same UUIDs will be handled correctly if the VG was inactive at the time of cloning: the already-activated version of the VG will take priority over the inactive extra copy, and LVM commands will complain loudly about the out-of-sync extra copy and refuse to do make any changes to the cloned VGs until the extra copy has been given a distinct identity by changing its UUIDs.

(I had to untangle some LVM volume group conflicts in a system that extensively used SAN storage-based on-line snapshots as a first step in cloning disks. No production data was lost, mostly because Linux LVM steadfastly refused to make any state changes once a conflict was detected, until the people responsible for the mess recognized they were in over their heads and started looking for help.)

Comment: Wow! As I was reading what you wrote, I knew this was the answer I was looking for. Thank you for the straight forward simple answer. As soon as I renamed the VG, and then changed the VG, I was able to mount the VG. Thank you again telcoM!